# Count or Sum values in a column separated by a comma in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope someone can help me.

I'm looking to find the total of multiple values from the same field in excel is it possible?

My sample column is:

```
0,0,1,1,1,2
```

I would like to add all these values together and have a total column in the output

Thanks

Comment: Which is your database?

Comment: Would you like to get something telling you that there are 2 `0`'s, 3 `1`'s and 1 `2`? If so, I would split the cell by comma delimited and transpose the data. Then, run a pivot table with a count on the records. This is in excel as you asked. If you would like, I can expand more on how to do this.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response its not exactly what I need i'm looking to do this from an oracle database and display it as a field. The numbers can change so I can have one row 0,0,1,1,1,2 I want the number 5 to display but the next row could be 1,1,2,6,10 so I would need 20 to display in the total column

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma-separated values in a single column in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  lv_formula VARCHAR2(1000):='0,0,1,1,1,2';
  result NUMBER;
BEGIN
    lv_formula:=replace(lv_formula, ',', '+');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :out := '||lv_formula||'; END;' USING OUT result;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Answer is...' || result);
END;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response its not exactly what I need i'm looking to do this from an oracle database and display it as a field. The numbers can change so I can have one row 0,0,1,1,1,2 I want the number 5 to display but the next row could be 1,1,2,6,10 so I would need 20 to display in the total column

Answer (score 5):

```
select 
  id, 
  list,
  sum(regexp_substr(list, '\d+', 1, occ)) as total
from 
  your_table,
  (select level occ from dual connect by level < 2000)
group by id, list
order by 1
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e403/5)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @techdo's answer (and please upvote or accept his answer - all I'm doing is fleshing this out) here's a way to do it:

First, build a function to implement @techdo's code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SUM_CSV(pin_Csv IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
  DETERMINISTIC
IS
  strFormula VARCHAR2(1000);
  nResult    NUMBER;
BEGIN
  strFormula := REPLACE(pin_Csv, ',', '+');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :out := ' || strFormula || '; END;' USING OUT nResult;
  RETURN nResult;
END SUM_CSV;
```

Note that the function must be deterministic - that is, it always produces the same results for a given input value.

Then create a table containing a virtual column which invokes the function SUM_CSV:

```
CREATE TABLE csv_test
  (text  VARCHAR2(1000),
   total NUMBER AS (SUM_CSV(text)));  -- virtual column
```

Now, insert into the table:

```
INSERT INTO CSV_TEST(TEXT) VALUES('1,2,3,4,5');
```

Commit the insert, then fetch the values back:

```
SELECT * FROM CSV_TEST;
```

And you get

```
TEXT            TOTAL
1,2,3,4,5       15
```

Share and enjoy.